# How to find out the number of combinations?

Tags: python, math

How can I find out the number of combinations that can be obtained from the read function?

## card.py:

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self, data, color):
        self.data = data
        self.color = color

    def is_correct(self):
        return True

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Card):
            return False
        return self.data == other.data and self.color == other.color

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)


letters = [
    "X",  # 0
    "C",  # 1
    "L",  # 2
    "S",  # 3
    "N",  # 4
    "T",  # 5
    "O",  # 6
    "I",  # 7
    "R",  # 8
    "A",  # 9
    "E"  # 10
]
```

## main.py

```py
from card import *

card = Card([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
], (255, 0, 0))


def read(inp):
    code = []
    if inp.is_correct():
        for i in range(0, 4, 2):
            sub_code = []
            for el1, el2 in zip(inp.data[i], reversed(inp.data[i + 1])):
                if el1 and el2:
                    sub_code.append(1)
            code.append(letters[len(sub_code)])
        for i in range(4, 9, 2):
            sub_code = []
            for el1, el2 in zip(inp.data[i], reversed(inp.data[i + 1])):
                if el1 and el2:
                    sub_code.append(1)
            code.append(len(sub_code))
        if inp.color[0] > inp.color[1] and inp.color[0] > inp.color[2]:
            code.append("#")
        elif inp.color[1] > inp.color[2] and inp.color[1] > inp.color[0]:
            code.append("_")
        elif inp.color[2] > inp.color[0] and inp.color[2] > inp.color[1]:
            code.append("!")
        elif inp.color[0] == inp.color[1] == inp.color[2]:
            code.append("?")
        else:
            code.append(".")
    return code


print(read(card))
```

Card has two fields:
data - it contains an array of length 10 and each element in this array is an array of length 10, each element of which is 1 or 0, the first four arrays in data denote two letters, all the rest are numbers;
color - is a tuple of colors in RGB format, which is denoted by a symbol at the end;

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have 10 arrays with 10 elements each you have 100 elements, and if each element can have 2 possible values, you have 2 to the power of 100 possible combinations. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Actually no, I'm interested in the number of combinations I can get with the read function.

Comment: This looks very easy, why don't you do it yourself?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone, I found a solution.

```py
from card import letters

a = 0

for let in letters:
    for le in letters:
        for i in range(11):
            for j in range(11):
                for l in range(11):
                    for symbol in ["#", "_", "!", "?", "."]:
                        print([let, le, i, j, l, symbol])
                        a += 1
print(a)
```

Or: `11 * 11 * 11 * 11 * 11 * 5 = 805255`